# Woocommerce product option - Highlight selected option(s)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building an e-commerce base on Woocommerce platform and struggling with one thing.
On the product page I have some options the user can choose from:
[image]

On this first picture, no option is selected.

When a user selects an option, I'd like it to be circled in black, or any indicator to show which option is selected. Right now, it is impossible to see which option is selected:

[image]

The options are simple Woocommerce options (images). Is there any way I could indicate to the user which options are selected by using css or javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Chrome, select one option for your product, then right-click -> inspect ("inspecter" in french).
Look at the parent elements (divs obviously) containing the selected element, it should have a "`selected`" class added to it, or an equivalent class, like maybe "`active`" or "`select`" or something else.
Now that you know the class added to selected options, you can add a CSS style like so :

```
.selected {border: 1px solid black;}
```

Add this style inside the "custom css" of your woocommerce theme, or in a custom css file in your theme.
Also this is just an example, it is better to be very specific about the element you are targeting in CSS to prevent all elements with .selected class have a border on you site.
For example, use :

```
.woocommerce-product.choice.selected {border:1px solid black;}
```

But this will depend on the configuration of your woocommerce theme, i cannot give precise answer without seeing the site.